# IBM Bluemix Error while creating Object Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am right now starting with BI in IBM Bluemix and I try to create an Object Storage but I am keeping to get all the time the same Error, and I don't know what is wrong. Any help would be good.

This is the messege I get when I click on create:

> A problem has occurred while creating an Object Storage instance.
>   Try again later.

Comment: Removed tags from title; spelling; grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing usually happens if your first and/or last name in your IBM account has numeric characters, Object Storage does not allow numeric characters in the first or last name and will fail creating the instance.

The only fix is to modify your Bluemix account name to remove any disallowed characters.

If that is your case you can fix your Bluemix account name by signing in to My IBM Profile (https://www.ibm.com/account/profile/us) and click "Edit user information".